# What are all the usages of ether?

Tags: ether, gas, dapp-development

I know that gas is used to keep contracts running but what are other usages for ether? Is ether used for buying all kinds of virtual tokens, will you need ether to use dapps or how is ether going to be used in ethereum economy?

Please provide as much information as you can on this issue.